# Two-cell lithium-ion battery balance charger with mid resistor

Tags: lithium-ion, charger

I am using an [MP2672](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/MP2672/) IC that balance-charges a two-cell (7.4 V) Li-ion battery. The IC's datasheet details a typical application circuit as usual, and I tried to follow this as closely as possible.

However, I am having trouble understanding the purpose of a resistor on the diagram and furthermore the magnitude of resistance to select. It is circled below, and is connected to the "MID" pad of the IC.  This pad is also connected to the positive voltage of the first battery cell in the series.

The datasheet provides some graphs where a value of 17 mΩ is used, but wouldn't this be a wire's resistance? Can I have too low a resistance here?

[image: circuit]

Mention of mid resistor value:
[image: mention of mid resistor value]

Comment: Search datasheet for comment re needing an external resistor to limit balance.current. ||  I'm on my phone which makes things difficult

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think, 17 mΩ would kill the internal balancer FETs immediately. The datasheet specifies the low side FET resistance with 1.3 Ω and if we have a cell voltage of 3.6 V, the FET must dissipate close to 10 W, which is impossible for this tiny QFN chip case.

If you use 2 A charging current, which is the chip limit, take 10 % of this as balancer current for a start. This would need a bleeding resistor of 18 Ω/1 W at 3.6 V and limits the low side FET power dissipation to acceptable 52 mW, high side FET 84 mW.

I assume, there is a typo in the datasheet and the bleeding resistor is 17 Ω, not 17 mΩ.

Watch the chip temperature during balancing in both directions, before you use lower resistor values.

Comment: I have actually selected 200mA on the max charging current.  What sort of problems would one encounter if the mid resistor is too high?

Comment: @Feynman137 In this case 18 ohm is your lower limit, the bleeding current should be below the charge current. I would probably use 47-100 ohm here. There is no upper limit, but balancing would need too much time (hours) with resistors above 220 ohm.

Answer (score 1):

I've reached the same conclusion that 17mΩ is a typo. Some good additional evidence is in the Evaluation Board Schematic ([link](https://www.monolithicpower.com/en/documentview/productdocument/index/version/2/document_type/Datasheet/lang/en/sku/EV2672A-D-00A/document_id/9060/)), copied below that has two 33Ω resistors in parallel giving near 17Ω.

[image]